# Gnome Help persists on launching even without opening the application

Tags: gnome, services

I initially asked this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629855/gnome-help-persists-on-launching-even-without-opening-the-application) in Information Security then it was migrated to Unix & Linux community. However, I think this question is also specific to Ubuntu.

**TL;DR** The problem is that the Gnome Help (yelp) keeps launching even if I've never opened it.

At first, I thought that maybe I was hacked. But I observed the behavior for a day and this is what I found to be causing the issue:
*from /var/log/syslog*

```
Jan 21 13:51:43 one gsd-media-keys[2592]: message repeated 321 times: [ Could not find default application for 'ghelp' scheme]
```

I'm not sure if there is a service that triggers this action and I have no idea what it does and how to configure it. For now, I purged the yelp package so that Gnome Help window will not launch anymore. The issue still persists and makes it difficult for me to do any actions on my keyboard or mouse. When this problem occurs, I can only navigate my way into anything through alt+tab and alt+f4. Please advise.

Comment: What OS & release are you asking about?  The *snap* or *deb* package version?   Please provide specifics.

Comment: @guiverc I'm using Ubuntu 20 LTS and only packages from _deb_.

Comment: Ubuntu has both *yy* (or year) releases, and main *yy.mm* (or *year.month*) releases.  All *yy* releases come with 10 years of support, so please clarify - there is no Ubuntu 20 LTS.

Comment: @guiverc Here are the details:
`$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find anything on the internet about this issue. For now, here is the workaround I've done to (somehow) fix it:

1. Do another round of an OS installation. Make sure to wipe drive.
2. Upon completing the installation, uninstall ***yelp***. Do this before connecting to the internet.
3. Connect to the internet and do a `sudo apt-get update`. Install only what you need, upgrade the necessary packages. Make sure you are only downloading from trusted sources.

**Update 1:** Here's another workaround: I did another round of OS installation but without any wm(Gnome). With a base OS, I installed i3. It worked and the issue no longer exists.